# Hyper-V/Ubuntu server 12.04 - VM does not stop

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, ubuntu-12.04

i just installed a ubuntu 12.04 server on a 2008 R2 Hyper-V server and all is fine (networking/storage ...). There is just one thing, when i halt my linux (using "sudo halt"), i can see on the console that the system is halted but the vm status on hyper-v is still "started". Then i need to stop it on the hyper-v management tool.

Anybody has an idea on how to properly stop this VM on hyper-V automatically ?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V will shut the VM down if Ubuntu writes to the control register that turns the machine off, as described in the ACPI specification.  Perhaps your Ubuntu installation has ACPI turned off?